# Sorting on various fields in a list

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class called ProviderOfficeData.  It has a lot of fields but the ones I am interested in:

```
`boolean primary;
String add1;
String add2;
boolean isPrimaryAddress() { return primary; }
String getAddress1() { return add1; }
String getAddress2() { return add2; }`
```

I want to sort alphabetically but primary (there is only 1) first.  I made the following sort and tried it but the primary was not at the top.  Any idea if there is a problem with the sort?

```
`public static class sortPrimaryFirst implements Comparator<ProviderOfficeData> {
        @Override
        public int compare(ProviderOfficeData cur, ProviderOfficeData nxt) {
            if (cur.isPrimaryAddress()) {
                return -1;
            }
            String curAdd = cur.getStreetAddress1() + "|" + cur.getStreetAddress2();
            String nxtAdd = nxt.getStreetAddress1() + "|" + nxt.getStreetAddress2();
            return curAdd.compareTo(nxtAdd);
        }
}`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know in which order sorting method will put arguments in `Comparator#compare()`, your `isPrimaryAddress` check should involve ***both*** of them:

```
if (cur.isPrimaryAddress() && !nxt.isPrimaryAddress()) {
    return -1;
} else if (!cur.isPrimaryAddress() && nxt.isPrimaryAddress()) {
    return 1;
} else {
    // compare other fields
}
```

Even if you know exactly, that only one instance with mentioned property exists in entire collection, this particular instance can be `cur` as well as `nxt` when `compare(cur, nxt)` is called.

Comment: They won't both be true but I think you are right I also need to check for it in nxt